# Full path of an exception in java

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to throw a custom exception

```
class NumberFormatException extends Exception
{
  public NumberFormatException() {}

  //Constructor that accepts a message
  public NumberFormatException(String message)
  {
    super(message);

  }
}
```

Later, I am throwing this exception using

```
 throw new NumberFormatException("Exception found");
```

and later on catching it using

```
catch(NumberFormatException e)
{
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

It prints something like

```
NumberFormatException: Exception found
```

Is it possible to print something like:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Exception found
```

The constraint is the `catch` code can't be modified i.e

```
catch(NumberFormatException e)
   {
     System.out.println(e);
   }
```

Comment: Don't make a custom "NumberFormatException" there is already one in Java and making your own with the same name will just cause pain and suffering...

Comment: I need it for handling custom case.

Comment: Give it a different name.

Comment: Why would your **custom** exception print `java.lang.NumberFormatException`?

Comment: as I earlier pointed out the `catch` component can't be modified.

Comment: Is there any way around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override `toString` In your `NumberFormatException` class :

```
class MyException extends Exception{
    String message;

    public MyException(String string) {
        this.message = string;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String s = getClass().getCanonicalName();
        String message = this.message;
        return (message != null) ? (s + ": " + message) : s;
    }
}
```

Source : [Throwable](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Throwable.java#Throwable.toString%28%29)

---

Here is a full code testing the method :

```
package first;

class MyException extends Exception{
    String message;

    public MyException(String string) {
        this.message = string;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String s = getClass().getCanonicalName();
        String message = this.message;
        return (message != null) ? (s + ": " + message) : s;
    }
}

public class TestingMyException{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            throw new MyException("This works !");
        }catch(MyException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Output**

```
first.MyException: This works !
```

Since my class is defined in the package named `first` of my root, the result prints `first.MyException`.

So you also have to check if your class is not defined in the ***default package***. Otherwise, you'll not get anything but :

```
MyException: This works !
```

Comment: I tried, gives same output `NumberFormatException: Exception found` . I guess since I am calling `super(message)`

Comment: Copy paste the method I have written. No more, no less. No need for super since you are overriding.

Comment: Yeah,I did the same thing inside the `NumberFormatException ` class.

Comment: Is there any other way?

Comment: Please check the edit. It works fine. Check out that you're not in the default package also.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get Canonical name of exception class and here is how you can get it:

```
catch(NumberFormatException e)
{
    System.out.println(e.getClass().getCanonicalName());
}
```

Refer javadoc for more : [getCanonicalName](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getCanonicalName())

Comment: as I earlier said the `catch` component can't be modified.

Comment: Is there any other way?